# mix object properties into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

What is the most efficient way to mix in the values from `extra` into `arr`, to produce `result` without modifying arr in any way? 
using: plain javascript, underscore, lodash(underscore compat), jquery OR lodash, in order of preference.

```
arr = [
  {name: "A"},
  {name: "B"},
  {name: "C"},
]
```

.

```
extra = {
  "B": value1
  "C": value2
}
```

.

```
result == [
  {name: "A"},
  {name: "B", extra: value1},
  {name: "C", extra: value2},
] 
// true !
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    if (arr[x].hasOwnProperty('name')) {
       if (extra.hasOwnProperty(arr[x].name)) {
           arr[x].extra = extra[arr[x].name];
       }
    }
}
```

The outer `hasOwnProperty` is probably overkill.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y3Abe/2/

Comment: I was in the middle of the same thing so I added my jsfiddle here and fixed a couple of missing `)`.

Comment: in this solution the objects in `arr` are modified. is there a way to do it making a deep clone of `arr` instead ?

Comment: @johowie you could use `_.clone` on the object beforehand maybe